# unable to send mail to multiple person in phpmailer

Tags: php, ssl, phpmailer

I am trying to send mail to multiple users using `phpmailer`.

What I am doing is that:

a) Firstly entering the email ids seperated by comma, let the user enters : `test@test.com,test1@test.com`

b) explode them into array:

```
$email_list = $_POST['emailid'];
$email_array = explode(',',$email_list);
```

c) Now the array of email is like

```
array('0'=>'test@test.com','1'=>'test1@test.com')
```

d) sending mail using phpmailer using foreach loop as follow :

```
foreach($email_array as $email_array )
            {
                $email = $email_array;
                //die;
                include('notification/class.phpmailer.php');

            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $body = $_POST['content'];

            $smtphost = get_option('smtphostlord');
            $smtpportlord = get_option('smtpportlord');
            $smtpemailord = get_option('smtpemailord');
            $smtppasslord = get_option('smtppasslord');


            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
            $mail->Host       = $smtphost;      // SMTP server
            $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;      // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)// 1 = errors and messages , // 2 = messages only
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;           // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
            $mail->Host       = $smtphost;      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
            $mail->Port       = $smtpportlord;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
            $mail->Username   = $smtpemailord;  // GMAIL username
            $mail->Password   = $smtppasslord;            // GMAIL password
            $mail->Subject    = $subject;
            $mail->MsgHTML($body);
            echo $email;
            $mail->AddAddress($email);  // sending email to
            echo $mail->Send();
                    $wpdb->query("insert into `sendmail_lordlinus`(`id`,`email`,`subject`,`body`,`sent`) values('','$email','$subject','$body','1')");  
            }
```

But when I am trying to send mail from the frontend, then it sends mail to only first email- id and `die the code` without any error:

What I am missing in this code ?

Thanks

Comment: you shouldn't make an `include` into a loop ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your first line to

`foreach($email_array as $email )`

and remove the following line which should become useless :

`$email = $email_array;`

Comment: what if you do the include before the loop?

Comment: thats only I am not able to figure out. I am trying to figure out, I'll catch you soon as soon as I got the answer

Answer (score 1):

I got my solution. I just put the `include()` statment above the `foreach` loop, and it worked for me